# How to compare strings in groovy script

Tags: groovy

I cannot understand why my simple `String` equality test is returning false.

Code is:

```
boolean isDevelopment() {
        //config.project_stage is set to "Development"
        String cfgvar = "${config.project_stage}" 
        String comp = "Development"
        assert cfgvar.equals(comp)
    }
```

Result is:

```
assert cfgvar.equals(comp)
       |      |      |
       |      false  Development
       Development
```

I also get false if I do:

```
assert cfgvar == comp
```

Answer (score 6):

`toString()` is not necessary. Most probably you have some trailing
spaces in `config.project_stage`, so they are retained also in `cfgvar`.

`comp` has no extra spaces, what can be seen from your code.

Initially the expression `"${config.project_stage}"` is of `GString`
type, but since you assign it to a variable typed as `String`,
it is coerced just to `String`, so `toString()` will not change anything.

It is up to you whether you use `equals(...)` or `==`.
Actually Groovy silently translates the second form to the first.

So, to sum up, you can write `assert cfgvar.trim() == comp`.

You can also trim `cfgvar` at the very beginning, writing:

```
cfgvar = "${config.project_stage}".trim()
```

and then not to worry about any trailing spaces.

Comment: nice summary. Thanks Valdi!

Answer (score 3):

Have you checked for trailing spaces? At least your output as one for the first `Development`. Try a .trim() when you compare those strings (and maybe a .toLowerCase() too)

<s>And remember: `.equals()` in Groovy is a pointer comparison. What want to do is `==`. Yes, just the opposite from what it is defined in Java, but the Groovy definition makes more sense :-)</s>

**Update**: see comment by @tim_yates - I mixed `.equals()` up with `.is()`

Comment: `equals` is not a pointer comparison in Groovy...  [You're thinking of `is()`](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/groovy-jdk/java/lang/Object.html#is(java.lang.Object))

Comment: This one did work rtn = cfgvar.toString().trim() == comp. I'm so happy!!! Thanks rdmueller :-). It may not be syntactically perfect but after struggling for 2 hours with it I don't care. I have a deadline. Thanks again for the quick help!!!

Answer (score 1):

On of the objects you comparing is not a `String` but `GString`, try:

```
cfgvar.toString().equals(comp)
```

However your code works with groovy v. 2.4.5. Which version are you using?

Comment: I am using version 2.4.5. but cfgvar.toString().equals(comp) also returns false.

Comment: Afaik it is not a GString - just a variable replacement. GString would be `"${-> something}"` , wouldn't it?

Comment: @rdmueller it would not.